# bxSlider: changes order of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I've got a problem with displaying bxslider carousel.

HTML (with WP path var) before JS:

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="1" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="2" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="3" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="4" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="5" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="6" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="7" /></li>
      <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slides/slide1_193x142.jpg" title="8" /></li>
    </ul>
```

JS code:

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 4,
      maxSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 233,
      slideMargin: 0,
      controls: false,
      pager: false,
      auto: true,
      autoStart: true,
      moveSlides: 1,
      captions: true,
      infiniteLoop: true,
      onSliderLoad: function(){$('.bxslider').css('display', 'block');}
    });
```

**After load i get slides starting from slibe №5 not №1, and after autostart with infiniteloop - it skips #1 slide and goes directly to №2**

Here's the demo:
http://olegzharov.com/

Tried:
- goToNextSlide
- goToSlide

But couldn't make it, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What is the exact problem. The slides start from number 1 - 8. WHat problem do you see?

Comment: look perfect for me check out again..

Comment: Exact problem is that after load i see slide #5, not #1...

Comment: I don't know about bxSlider, but what do those `minSlides` and maxSlides` parameters mean exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I thought that problem was in conlict between js libraries/jQuery plugins = no

2) I thought that problem was with markup, callback = no

I looked throught generated code and found that bxSlider creates 8 additional slides with bx-clone class, so i just hacked it with

```
/* WRONG START SLIDE FIX */

.bx-clone {
    display: none;
}
```

Didn't read much about bx-clone, but after 2 days f***king with it, this solution is good for me enough.

P.S. This doesn't work properly, because hides slides in infinite loop.

So I did it that way (hiding images with css on load, and showing after load, not the container):

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // Slider for main page

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 4,
          maxSlides: 4,
          slideWidth: 233,
          slideMargin: 0,
          controls: false,
          pager: false,
          auto: true,
          autoStart: true,
          moveSlides: 1,
          captions: true,
          infiniteLoop: true,
          onSliderLoad: function(){$('.bxslider li img').css('display', 'block');}
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code for bxslider in fiddle it works fine. But I do see it functioning differently in your demo URL.

Try one of these 2 to see if it helps :

1) **startSlide** option: specify the slide you wish to start with. 0 for 1st slide, 1 for 2nd and so on.

```
  var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      infiniteLoop: true,
      speed: 500,
      minSlides: 4,
      startSlide:3,
      maxSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 233,
      slideMargin: 0,
      controls: false,
      pager: false,
      auto: true,
      autoStart: true,
      moveSlides: 1,
      captions: true,
      onSliderLoad: function(){$('.bxslider').css('display', 'block');}
 });
```

2) **goToSlide** function call.

Use the slider variable. See the code above and call the function goToSlide after the images have loaded to specifically slide to the desired slide number.

```
slider.goToSlide(0);
```

Check the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FwcTy/)

Comment: thanks for your response, but as i mentioned before - I tried goToSlide and goToNexSlide and startSlide - nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent cloning you must set the `infiniteLoop` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these work for me, including the accepted answer. I changed the startslide to -1, and that fixed it. Not ideal, but it works.